# Download SharePoint file from Microsoft Graph API using "sourcedoc" ID

Tags: sharepoint, office365, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to download a SharePoint file from the MS Graph `/drive/items/xxxx` API endpoint. The link I have is in the format `https://company-my.sharepoint.com/personal/drive_name/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B<GUID>%7D`, but the graph API needs some other OneDrive file ID to successfully fetch file metadata.

I have the correct permission scopes, and if I enumerate drive contents I can see the file there.

Is there any way to convert the `sourcedoc` guid into what is required by the API, or alternatively get file metadata by SharePoint guid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you're after is the [Shares API](https://dev.onedrive.com/shares/shares.htm). Given a URL like the one you used in your example you need to convert it to a `share id` value using [this algorithm](https://dev.onedrive.com/shares/shares.htm#encoding-sharing-urls).

So for your example the id be:

```
u!aHR0cHM6Ly9jb21wYW55LW15LnNoYXJlcG9pbnQuY29tL3BlcnNvbmFsL2RyaXZlX25hbWUvX2xheW91dHMvMTUvV29waUZyYW1lLmFzcHg_c291cmNlZG9jPSU3QjxHVUlEPiU3RA
```

With this value you can then query the item's metadata using:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/u!aHR0cHM6Ly9jb21wYW55LW15LnNoYXJlcG9pbnQuY29tL3BlcnNvbmFsL2RyaXZlX25hbWUvX2xheW91dHMvMTUvV29waUZyYW1lLmFzcHg_c291cmNlZG9jPSU3QjxHVUlEPiU3RA/root
```